# ngStorage not accessible in Controller

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and Angular JS. I have an app.js and a controller.js.

I get connection type in app.js like this

```
  if(window.Connection){
  $localStorage.connection = navigator.connection.type
         }
```

When I Try to access $localStorage.connection  in my controller.js like this

```
alert($localStorage.connection);
```

$$localStorage.connection  is empty.

Please how do I Access a value stored in app.js using ngStorage in my Controller.js ?

Comment: can you put your code in codepen or github to have a look so that we will get an idea, how to solve it

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNLyPa.  please notice i put both the app.js and controller.js in the js window.

Answer (score 0):

`ngStorage` behavior is not persistent with ionic applications when you are running them on real devices,storage variables return empty values, so i would suggest you to use `angular-local-stroage`, here is the [documentation](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But the issue is my controller.js runs before my app.js. Because I define this variable within the app.js it returns null when i try to access it within the controller.js.